# Reduce vertical padding of itemize inside tabular

Tags: tables, itemize

I am using this code to create itemize within a tabular environment.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{0.4cm}
    \begin{tabular}{| m{2cm} | m{4cm} | m{4cm} | m{4cm} |}
        \hline
        Verticals & Drivers & Enablers & 5G requirement \\
        \hline
        Education & 
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item Remote delivery 
            \item Immersive experiences 
        \end{itemize} & 
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item Video streaming 
            \item Augmented reality 
            \item Virtual reality 
        \end{itemize} & 
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item Large bandwidth 
            \item Low latency 
        \end{itemize} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which results in this

[image]

As you can see, it has a large amount of vertical space just before the list starts and after it ends.

How can I get a tighter vertical layout?

Comment: this answer should point you in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

The `enumitem` package allows you to customize virtually all aspects of an `itemize`-like environment. An application of this idea to your formatting objective leads to the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1} % create a bespoke 1-level itemize-like env.
\setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet, nosep, leftmargin=*, 
                     before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\RaggedRight},
                     after={\end{minipage}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| p{2cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} |}
        \hline
        Verticals & Drivers & Enablers & 5G requirement 
        \\
        \hline
        Education & 
        \begin{tabitemize}   
            \item Remote delivery
            \item Immersive experiences 
        \end{tabitemize} & 
        \begin{tabitemize} 
            \item Video streaming 
            \item Augmented reality 
            \item Virtual reality 
        \end{tabitemize} & 
        \begin{tabitemize} 
            \item Large bandwidth 
            \item Low latency 
        \end{tabitemize} 
        \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of editing the details of the `tabitemize` environment.